# Value < of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray In Android

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, html

I'm trying to upload the image in Samsung j7 camera. I get some server response with `</div>` tag.

How can I resolve this error and what is the way to get the image from the response?

Error Image Form Android Server Response

[image]

My code

- protected void Upload_Server() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      String urlServer = null;
      System.out.println("After call progress");
      try{

  ```
      Log.e("Image Upload", "Inside Upload");

      HttpURLConnection connection = null;
      DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
      DataInputStream inputStream = null;

      String pathToOurFile = imagepath;
      //   String pathToOurFile1 = imagepathcam;

      System.out.println("Before Image Upload" + imagepath);
      if(Videoboolean){
          urlServer = Constants.IMAGEVIDEOURL+"videopostUpload/";
      }else {
          urlServer = Constants.IMAGEVIDEOURL+"imagepostUpload/";
      }

      System.out.println("URL SETVER" + urlServer);
      System.out.println("After Image Upload" + imagepath);
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary =  "*****";

      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
      System.out.println("enter the file path in android"+pathToOurFile);
      FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile));
      //  FileInputStream fileInputStream1 = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile1));

      URL url = new URL(urlServer);
      connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      System.out.println("URL is "+url);
      System.out.println("connection is "+connection);
      // Allow Inputs & Outputs
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);
      connection.setUseCaches(false);

      // Enable POST method
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

      connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

      outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
      outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
      outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
      outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
      System.out.println("enter the image upload response"+outputStream.getClass().getCanonicalName());
      bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
      bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
      buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

      // Read file
      bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

      while (bytesRead > 0)
      {
          outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
          bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
          bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
          bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
      }

      outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
      outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

      // Responses from the server (code and message)
      int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
      String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();


      System.out.println("image"+serverResponseMessage);

      fileInputStream.close();
      outputStream.flush();
      outputStream.close();

      DataInputStream inputStream1 = null;
      inputStream1 = new DataInputStream (connection.getInputStream());
      String str="";
      String Str1_imageurl="";

      while ((  str = inputStream1.readLine()) != null)
      {
          Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);

          Str1_imageurl = str;
          Log.e("Debug","Server Response String imageurl"+str);
      }
      inputStream1.close();
      System.out.println("image url"+Str1_imageurl);

      PostImVD = Str1_imageurl.trim();
      JSONArray array = new JSONArray(PostImVD);
      JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(0);
      if(Videoboolean){
          ImageVideo = jsonObj.optString("video_name");
      }else {
          ImageVideo = jsonObj.optString("image_name");
      }
      System.out.println("Profile Picture Path" + PostImVD);
      System.out.println("Profile Picture Path" + ImageVideo);
  }

  catch(Exception e){

      e.printStackTrace();

  }
  ```

  };

  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZEl2.png): [Error Image Form Android Server Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZEl2.png)

Comment: Server response is not JSON obviuosly. And you try to convert it to JSONArray

Comment: Also please format your question not to use **bold** for whole question, it makes me not to want to help you.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing where the `javascript`, `php` and `html`-tags come into play

Comment: I convert the JSONArray but can't able to get the Result

Answer (score 0):

First, try to validate your JSON response in this page for example:

https://jsonlint.com/

If your JSON is correct, then determine if is an array or an object, depends of that use the correct parsing :

If it's an array:

```
 JSONArray array = new JSONArray(your_string_json);
```

If it's an object

```
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(your_string_json);
```

Comment: Ok I try this one but How can I Remove the </div>  tag because the Response format is   </div>[{"status":"Success","imageurl":"http:\/\/138.68.151.147\/images\/users\/8a1c38f057eafa00c6ae5d1ff3a4c6ff.jpg","image_name":"8a1c38f057eafa00c6ae5d1ff3a4c6ff.jpg"}]

Comment: You should not do that, the server must return a valid content response, but If you want to parse , try to use     string.substring(6)

Comment: Can You give Me the Reference  code For the Splitting because I can't able to split it Out

Comment: String value = "your_string_with_div";
String parsed = value.substring(6);
Print parsed if you are not sure :)